# Filtering content of list from the value selected in dropdown list

Tags: data-view-web-part

I want to filter the contain of list based on the value selected in drop down list of data view webpart.
I am using javascript to get the value which is selected now how I can use the value which is selected for filtering.
I dont know how to use the value which is returned by javascript in xslt?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Manish,

I have written a blog for filtering lists [External List but applies to Custom List as well], please have a look:
[External List with BCS & Search Filters](http://arsalkhatri.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/external-list-with-bcs-search-filters-finders/)

I have used External List but you can use Custom List as well and I have used Textboxes but you can use drop down lists!

I hope this helps..